# formsauthenticationticket is decrypted with previous login data

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that uses Active Directory membership for user authentication.

After the user logs in, a `FormsAuthenticatedTicket` is created and encrypted. Then, in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` the ticket is decrypted and the deserialized user data is stored in a custom principal object.

i have changed the expiration date of ticket from AddMinute(30) to AddMenute(10)

My problem is that when a user logs in after their cookie has expired, the ticket is encrypted with the current login data, but in global.asax the previous login's ticket is still decrypted. When debugging, I have seen the ticket data of the previous expiration date (after 30 minute not 10 minutes) of the same user with ticket version decrypted to 2.

What mistake did I make?

---

**Edit :**
i resolved this problem with removing  `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);`
because i have used the FormsAuthenticationTicket object

but I am in front of another problem:
in global asax Application_PostAuthenticateRequest, when trying to reading the cookie, i have found by debugger that's null although the cookie added with ticket encrypted successfuly

```
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

i have two users : this probleme occurs with one of them but with the other there's no probleme

please, how to resolve this problem? 
Web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login">
    </forms>
 </authentication>

 <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">  
   <providers>
     <clear/>
     <add name="ADMembershipProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
          connectionStringName ="ADconnectionString"
           attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />  

    </providers>  
 </membership>
```

my post action login methode

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
    {
        ViewBag.Message = FormattedMessage.GetFormattedMessage("Veuillez Entrer l'utilisateur et/ou mot passe", TypeMessage.Danger, true);
        return this.View();
    }

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
    {
        //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
        //JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); 
        var userAD = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);
        var intervenant = unitOfWorkBll.UserBLL.GetAllFiltered(u => u.Matricule == userAD.EmployeeId, includes: "IntervenantRoles.Role, IntervenantStructures.Structure").SingleOrDefault();
        //string userData = js.Serialize(intervenant);
        string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(intervenant, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        });
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),rememberMe, userData);

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) )
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    ViewBag.Message= FormattedMessage.GetFormattedMessage("l'utilisateur et /ou le mot passe incorrect.", TypeMessage.Danger, true);

    return this.View();
}
```

global asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie autoCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (autoCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(autoCookie.Value);
        Intervenant user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Intervenant>(ticket.UserData/*, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        }*/);

        CustomADPrincipal customADPrincipal = new CustomADPrincipal(user); ;

        HttpContext.Current.User = customADPrincipal;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the source of problem : i have used the eager loading so the length of userdata is more large, therefor the ticket could not be decrypted that's why a cookie is null in global.asax